# Assign new variable from one df to another df, based on shared columns/conditions

Tags: r

I have two df which have two same columns

```
> DF1
   col1 col2 col3 col4
1     A    C    22   NA
2     B    D    58   NA
3     A    E    35   NA
4     B    C    86   NA
5     A    D    37   NA
6     B    E    16   NA
7     A    C    46   NA
8     B    D    23   NA
9     A    E    88   NA
10    B    C     3   NA
> DF2
  col1 col2 new_var 
1    A    C    1     
2    A    D    3    
3    A    C    1    
4    A    D    3    
5    A    C    1    
6    A    D    3
```

Now I want to merge the `new_var` from DF2 to DF1. I’ve tried the following code, but the value of `new_var` in the newly joined df is always 0. Anyone has any idea on this?

```
df1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new_var = length(df2$new_var[which(col1 == df2$col1) & (col2 == df2$col2)]))
```

Comment: Maybe you need `left_join(df1, df2)`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `.` refering to `df1`? The error can be there: %>% 
  mutate(new_var = length(df2$new_var[which(.$col1 == df2$col1) & (.$col2 == df2$col2)]))

Comment: Hi @nniloc `left_joint()` would actually leave the value of `new_var` at `NA`.

Comment: @Sebek Could you pls elaborate? Tried that and it makes no difference. Thanks.

Comment: Using dplyr, i usually use .$col to enter a column on a df i'm working with. I thought that if you had a problem, it may be caused by incomprehension between that two dataframes inside pipe operator. But seems that this was not the case and the code runs as always. @HPham

Comment: Would be helpful if you added your expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a [merge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/merge) here.

```
DF_combined <- merge(x=DF1, y=DF2, by=c("col1", "col2"), all.x=TRUE)
DF_combined
   col1 col2 col3 col4 new_var
1     A    C   22   NA       1
2     A    C   22   NA       1
3     A    C   22   NA       1
4     A    C   46   NA       1
5     A    C   46   NA       1
6     A    C   46   NA       1
7     A    D   37   NA       3
8     A    D   37   NA       3
9     A    D   37   NA       3
10    A    E   88   NA      NA
11    A    E   35   NA      NA
12    B    C   86   NA      NA
13    B    C    3   NA      NA
14    B    D   58   NA      NA
15    B    D   23   NA      NA
16    B    E   16   NA      NA
```

However, in your `DF2` you do not have unique identifiers based on `col1` and `col2` and they perhaps should.

Comment: Thanks for you response. But this results in `NA` for the value of `new_var`.

Comment: Does this mean I need to create an ID column for my `DF2`? @slackline

Comment: There are _some_ instances of `NA` in the merged data frame. Looking at the first instance it is because there is no data in `DF2` for anyone with the value `col1 == A` and `col2 == E`. Looking closer you also have duplicates in `DF1`  based on `col1` and `col2`.

It may be that you have created a "Minimal Reproducible Example" to ask this question and that is why but you do not need to create an ID column in either data frame and should probably look for unique identifiers unless you have repeated measures data in one data frame.